# how to change css transform-origin but preserve transformation

Tags: css, css-transforms

The bigger picture of this question is that I have a transformed map which needs to respond to touch gestures, it needs to scale and rotate from the center of the users gesture.

The transform-origin needs to change on every new gesture but without changing the rotation and scale, basically I imagine adding a translation to compensate for the change in transform-origin?

Or if there is a way to use matrix transform to preserve the transform while changing the transform-origin?

Comment: Without an actual code snippet that reproduce the issue, this is a too broad question.

Comment: I don't agree, the question is specific, how to change the transform-origin on an element with an arbitrary rotation, scale and translation but preserving the original transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this, but it sounds like you are on the right track. I created a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/btpoe/pen/QGvNge) to prototype it out and it seems like the trick is to add a negative offset to the beginning your translate followed by a positive offset at the end.

```
.box {
    transform: rotateX(45deg) scale(1.4);
    transform-origin: 10px 10px;
}

.box.is-active {
    transform: translate(-50px, -50px) rotateX(45deg) scale(1.4) translate(50px, 50px);
    transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}
```

I'm not sure how this would behave with a more complex transforms, but it seems to work fine with simple ones.

Comment: that is interesting, could you explain what is going on there with the negative first and then positive after as to why that's needed? it also looks like the values are the delta of the transform-origins is that right?

Comment: also interested how this would work if you also already have a translation on the orginal (which is my case)

Comment: also because the order of operation of the transforms is right to left, the negative translation comes last right?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is the delta of the transform origins
2) It should work fine with an existing transform, just be sure to make the delta account for it
3) I believe transforms are applied left to right

Comment: Actually, I went and looked it up and you are correct, the transforms are applied right to left, so technically the positive translate is applied first.

Comment: so whilst this does preserve the transform while changing origin, which is great, the problem is that I need to apply new scaling and rotation around the new origin based on the user touch gesture (pinch zoom etc.).